# how to kill php/apache child process in windows when we run several ajax requests

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, windows

I have a loop that sends lots of ajax to server. Each ajax downloads from ftp a file. I want to kill all php/ftp or apache children. I am killing the javascript through windows.stop(). The php scripts that are already running don't die (thus, they still download the files), just the others that were supposed to be called but are not called yet, that "die".
I am running apache under windows.

Comment: `XHR.abort()` in JS usually works on pending requests.  `var request = $.post(...); request.abort();`  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/abort   `- The XMLHttpRequest.abort() method aborts the request if it has already been sent`

Comment: Hey, i tried abort, but it didnt work out. I think abort is for ajax, not the php that are already running on the server side.

Comment: If I remember there is a setting somewhere that changes that.

Comment: The php still runs even if i kill/abort the ajax related with it.

Comment: Additionally, in WAMP I've found that restarting the server is needed to terminate processes reliably.  But that is probably overkill in your case

Comment: Here it is .. http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php  `ignore_user_abort(false)` not sure if it will work.  `ignore_user_abort() — Set whether a client disconnect should abort script execution`

Comment: No matter how you do `unless you kill the process with command line, such as by process id` you have to do something from inside the executing script to check if it should die.

Comment: I was going to try the command line, but dont know how to find all apache's process id children.

Comment: Isn't ignore_user_abort() false by default? It seems to be! Anyway, tried that, didn't work out.

Comment: It has the same requirements for output getting the pid is easy from inside the process `http://php.net/manual/en/function.getmypid.php`  from outside on linux you have to use `ps aux|grep`  with the filename or such, and a bit of mucking around and then your code is less portable etc...

Comment: I dont know the contest, but maybe for each request, open a new process for it and store the process id(remove on done). then kill the remaining Id on stop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i used:

`$pid= getmypid();
exec("Taskkill /f /PID ".$pid);`

It solves my problem!!! Thanks to all!